# Add any arbitrary header to nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Let's say that you want to add a custom response header in `nginx`, but only on certain conditions.

If you search around, you'll find this recipe (for adding a `Retry-After` header while rate limiting)

```
map $status $my_response {
  default "";
  "429" "5";
}

server {
   ...
   add_header Retry-After $my_response always;
   ...
}
```

But what if you want the header on some other condition?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `map` is very, very powerful.

Let's say that you want something more granular? Or to use one of the other embedded variables. The `limit_conn` module has one such var, [`$limit_conn_status`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html#limit_conn_status).

```
map $limit_conn_status $conn_response {
  "PASSED" "";
  "REJECTED" "Too many concurrent connections";
  "REJECTED_DRY_RUN" "Too many concurrent connections (dry run)";
}

limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:1m;

server {
  ...
  limit_conn one 1;
  add_header X-Custom-Header $conn_response always;
  ...
}
```

This is independent of the `$status` code! And when things are "passing" the header value is blank, so the header is not returned in the response.